# Mongoose not creating text indexes for multiple fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a basic mongoose schema that requires me to create a text index on two of its fields: name & description.

Here are my mongoose connection options:

```
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);

const mongoOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  autoIndex: false,
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  reconnectInterval: 500,
  poolSize: 10,
  bufferMaxEntries: 0
};

mongoose.connect(MONGOURI, mongoOptions);
```

Here is my schema:

```
const ASchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, text: true, index: true, required: true, maxlength: [100, 'Name must be less than 100 characters']},
  description: {type: String, text: true, index: true, required: true, maxlength: [500, 'Description must be less than 500 characters']},
  meta: {tags: [String]}
});

ASchema.options.autoIndex = true;

ASchema.index({
  name: 'text',
  description: 'text',
}, {
  weights: {
    name: 5,
    description: 3,
  },
});

var A = mongoose.model("AModel", ASchema);

module.exports = A;
```

For some reason with the query, I create with:

```
app.post('/search', (req, res, next) => {
  let query = req.query.q
  console.log(query);
  A.find({
    $text: { $search: query }
  }, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
  ).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
  .then(q => {
    console.log(q); res.send(q)
  })
  .catch(next)
});
```

I will only ever get the results if my query string is within the **name** field.
Yet when I enter a sentence or word **ONLY** present in the description I am returned an empty ARRAY.

calling `db.amodels.getIndexes()` on my mongo shell returns the following:

```
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "adatabase.amodels"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_fts" : "text",
                        "_ftsx" : 1
                },
                "name" : "name_text",
                "ns" : "adatabase.amodels",
                "background" : true,
                "weights" : {
                        "name" : 1
                },
                "default_language" : "english",
                "language_override" : "language",
                "textIndexVersion" : 3
        }
]
```

I can see from this, as well as my mlab instance, that my **compound index** has not been created, nor has the proper weighting been assigned.

calling `db.amodels.ensureIndex({"description": "text"})`

returns a `IndexOptionsConflict`

```
{
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1565476058, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Index: { v: 2, key: { _fts: \"text\", _ftsx: 1 }, name: \"description_text\", ns: \"adatabase.amodels\", weights: { description: 1 }, default_language: \"english\", language_override: \"language\", textIndexVersion: 3 } already exists with different options: { v: 2, key: { _fts: \"text\", _ftsx: 1 }, name: \"name_text\", ns: \"adatabase.amodels\", background: true, weights: { name: 1 }, default_language: \"english\", language_override: \"language\", textIndexVersion: 3 }",
        "code" : 85,
        "codeName" : "IndexOptionsConflict",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1565476058, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"FMoSr4UQZWqocfrRTFvGoa62TsY="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6723301754588364801")
                }
        }
}
```

Have I messed up somewhere simply? I sure do hope so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mongoDB, you cannot create two text indexes i.e; two Single Field text indexes on two different fields of a collection. If really need to create, all you can do is to drop existing one (if it's ok) & create a new compound index with all necessary text fields !!  Below is for shell operation or as you already have compound index in schema, you can run your code.

Do something like this :

```
db.amodels.createIndex(
   {
     name: "text",
     description: "text"
   }
 )
```

With weights (Optional) :

```
db.amodels.createIndex(
    {
        name: "text",
        description: "text"
    },
    {
        weights: {
            name: 5,
            description: 3
        },
        name: "name_description"
    }
)
```

**Note :** Regd. your creation of indexes - You can start using `createIndex` as `ensureIndex` is deprecated  [ensureIndex to createIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/index.html)

Please check this for reference :

[MongoDB Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#restrictions?searchProperty=current&query=ensureIn)

Comment: thanks! works great now. Is there any way to implement creating this compound index directly into my code, instead of having to use the shell each time? EDIT: I've also just noticed the weights I have in my Schema file are not being implemented?

Comment: @Bdyce : You're creating compound index correctly in your schema, only issue is with mongoDB has already a text index, you cannot alter existing index like that, you need to drop it. I'm not exactly sure on mongoose dropIndex and then to create this using code !! what was the issue with weights?

Comment: After deleting all collections in the database. I reconnect, this runs my mongoose code where a compound index should be created on the instance. Instead, only the single text index on the "name" field is created.

`{
  "v": 2,
  "key": {
    "_fts": "text",
    "_ftsx": 1
  },
  "name": "name_text",
  "ns": "adatabase.amodels",
  "background": true,
  "weights": {
    "name": 1
  },
  "default_language": "english",
  "language_override": "language",
  "textIndexVersion": 3
}` 
As you can see here the weights I've included in the Schema file have not been placed in the index.

Comment: Upon dropping this single "name" index,  I have to then run `db.amodels.createIndex(
   {
     name: "text",
     description: "text"
   }
 )` In the shell in order to create the compound index. The weighting on this index is also simply {"name": 1, "description": 1} which is not the weighting within my Schema file?

Comment: @Bdyce : In your schema for name, description fields you're saying index : true, and ASchema.options.autoIndex = true :::> will create indexes for all fields for every mongoose restarts !! Personally, I would not recommend doing that, either remove those or set autoIndex = false and try dropping name text index and give it a try. (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)

Comment: after removing `autoindex` no indexes are created for the fields upon connection...The problem remains to be that upon connecting, my code should implement the respective compound index I've specified in the Schema file. This is not the case, only the `"name": "text" ` is created. Upon dropping this index, I create the compound index within the shell as per your instructions which works! but this does not include my weighting preferences for either of the fields? what am I missing in my mongoose code in order for the compound index and weights to be created on connection w/o needing the shell?

Comment: @Bdyce : Can you please remove "index : true" from your fields(just keep type,required,maxLength) and try, then mongoose shouldn't create any single field indexes, also if you want weights while doing from shell I think you're missing to include weights options that's the reason why it is picking defaults to 1 ...!!!!!

Comment: thanks for all the help, the problem didn't seem to be the `autoIndex: true` rather the `index: true` & `text: true` options on my fields. Cheers. Problem solved!

Comment: @Bdyce : Yes, that's correct !! as I've mentioned above "autoIndex: true" -- it will be true by default, you need to explicitly make it false, removing doesn't help, it would create indexes for every mongoose refresh automatically for all fields where index : true !!